# ASIHTTPRequest UIWebView load documents

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, asihttprequest

What is the best way to view documents (pdf,doc,xls) using AsiHttpRequest and UIWebView??? I tried the following, but the UIWebView is displaying the html:

```
NSString * baseURL = @"http://xxxxxx/open-api/v1/";
NSString * itemRef = @"item/133/attachment/test.pdf";

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", baseURL, itemRef];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setUsername:@"xx"];
[request setPassword:@"xx"];

[request startSynchronous];

NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error) {
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:[request responseString] baseURL: [request url]];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error );
}
```

AsiHttpRequest is required for setting Basic Authentication and Header Values... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, to be fair, you're telling it to display HTML, so the result isn't really unexpected :-)

You'd need to download the pdf file locally:

```
NSString *tmpLocation = // some temporary file location
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:tmpLocation]];
[request startSyncronous];
```

then view it in UIWebView:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:tmpLocation];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: Did u used it? It's not working if I am using NSTemporaryDirectory() for the temp location...

Comment: You'll need to add a filename onto the end of NSTemporaryDirectory(). (No, I've not tried directly this code, however it is the right way to do it and there's no reason it shouldn't work.)